# How to pass data by host page when using golang as gwt 's backend?

Tags: gwt, go

Currently,my configuration is like this:

```
gwt+nginx+golang
```

,and nginx works as a proxy that will redirect all requests(on port:80) to golang server(on port:8080).Since I use golang as backend,so I want user to access my website by

```
www.domain.com
```

directly without specifing host page like this:

```
www.domain.com/index.html.
```

I think it should be easy in production model:just proxy all requests on / to a golang service,question is on development model:without a host page,How to get gwt app run up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevMode is no different actually. Deploy a compiled version on your server once, then run DevMode in [`-noserver` mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s) passing it `-startupUrl http://www.domain.com`. It should Just Work™.